# How to install Swoole in ubuntu

Tags: swoole

Simply my Question is How to Install Swoole in **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I have tried

```
sudo pecl install swoole
```

am getting handfull of errors, already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355058/swoole-make-failed-ubuntu16-04)

Is there any alternate way to install the same...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swoole Installation alternate ways**

1.Install from source

```
sudo apt-get install php7-dev
git clone https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src.git
cd swoole-src
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

2.Example for static compile

```
git clone -b PHP-7.2 --depth 1 https://github.com/php/php-src.git
cd php-src/
git clone -b master --depth 1 https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src.git ext/swoole
./buildconf --force
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --disable-all --enable-cli --disable-cgi --disable-fpm --disable-phpdbg --enable-bcmath --enable-hash --enable-json --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-mbregex-backtrack --enable-sockets --enable-pdo --with-sodium --with-password-argon2 --with-sqlite3 --with-pdo-sqlite --with-pcre-regex --with-zlib --with-openssl-dir --enable-swoole-static --enable-openssl --with-swoole
time make -j `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`
sudo make install
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to run "make clean" before all steps.

Answer (score 5):

Some Linux distributions do not include the PHP-XML extension in their PHP package and will need to be enabled before using PECL. You can install using `apt-get install php-xml` and you may need to install PHPize to compile Swoole, you can install it using `apt-get install php7.*-dev` or whatever PHP version you are using.

Then try again with `sudo pecl install swoole`

Answer (score 4):

For those who installed PHP from ondrej/php PPA (quite common way to install PHP in Ubuntu) it's quite easy now:

`sudo apt install php-swoole`

Or for specific version:

`sudo apt install php7.4-swoole`

Tip. This is how you usually install ondrej/php PPA:

```sh
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

Install swoole for version specific should work for example if you have php 7.3 use

```
sudo apt install php7.3-swoole
```

replace the version to your local php env